# Is it possible to restore a btrfs snapshot with a different partition state?

Tags: linux, partitioning, btrfs

So, now i'm using Arch Linux and I already have btrfs snapshot with condition / and /home are in 1 partition (sda1).
I would separate the /home partition from / (sda2 for /home and sda1 for /).

my question is, is it possible to restore a btrfs snapshot with a different partition state (which previously had sda1 and sda2 being sda1 only)?

Comment: First of all, how do you plan to separate the filesystem to two partitions? Are you going to resinstall, rsync or just clone-and-delete-respectively? Or is `/home` a subvolume?

Comment: My home partition is not a subvolume so it's impossible huh? (I will not reinstall the operating system)

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what you mean by `restore a btrfs snapshot with a different partition state`, but if `/home` isn't a subvolume, one of the best way to relocate `/home` to a separate partition is mkfs and then rsync (and rm -R then mkdir afterwards, naturally).